# Can I use "there you are" when I finally find someone? because according to the Cambridge dictionary I can't

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "there you are" when I finally find someone?

Because according to the Cambridge dictionary I can't but I heard a native speaker say it.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there-you-go?q=there+you+are

Comment: The link you supply is for _there you go_. You can use _there you are_ with the same meaning, but you can also use it literally with the meaning that you want.

Comment: under "A2" it says (informal there you are)

Comment: Yes - that's why I said 'You can use _there you are_ with the same meaning [as _there you go_]'.

Comment: The reason why the dictionary doesn't have a specific entry for your usage is that it's not a fixed expression, it's just using the individual words according to their ordinary meaning.